# A Collatz like function or Eulers totient function vs. the sum of divisors?

Tags: number-theory, dynamical-systems, divisor-sum

Originally posted on MO, but it seems to be not a research level question:

Inspired by the Collatz function, I experimented with Euler's totient function $\phi$ vs. the sum of divisors function $\sigma$:

$$C(n) = \phi(n)\cdot\frac{(1+(-1)^n)}{2}+\sigma(n)\cdot\frac{(1-(-1)^n)}{2}$$

It seems that the only cycle is $1 \mapsto 1$ and that every number iterates to this cycle:

[Experiment.](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyNkUsLwjAMx-9-ioCXdvOxehR28r4vICLDZa4Ys9F1CH56u3UPJyjmUMjrl3_SDHO4lESpfQqW-wU4M2gbw4ANoTlXhXaJQKhQrJUMApbbXSjUevKCWl_vqSvqmv2TOSzp2h4G9CqJk5Kxn6BzSEDX0IZ8pDUiiOF4Gv28bDibhx6FJgQuLTBo9hUTwEM2aVUhZ4OgGe1LjuPpBl1i-Y4Z13o7DlEXQap_LmDg1uo0KV9RJPJPqewwH4JmoztBi5bOE12tVBRF_YjKaLZDr3dm3yHlCxS_gQ0=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

Example:

```
1
[1]
2
[2, 1]
3
[3, 4, 2, 1]
4
[4, 2, 1]
5
[5, 6, 2, 1]
6
[6, 2, 1]
7
[7, 8, 4, 2, 1]
8
[8, 4, 2, 1]
9
[9, 13, 14, 6, 2, 1]
10
[10, 4, 2, 1]
11
[11, 12, 4, 2, 1]
12
[12, 4, 2, 1]
13
[13, 14, 6, 2, 1]
14
[14, 6, 2, 1]
15
[15, 24, 8, 4, 2, 1]
16
[16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

Can this be proven? (I am having trouble understanding why $\sigma(2n+1)$ where $2n+1$ is a square, will not be an odd square number?

**Edit**:
As per comment of @Servaes the question boils down to show the following:

There is no odd number $m$, besides $1$, such that:

$$\sigma^{(k)}(m^2), \forall k \ge 0$$

is for all $k$ an odd square number?

[Here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyNksFuwyAMhu99CqvVJCDpNnKclF125wWmqUINaVGJkxGiSXv6QSglqbRpHJD82_n826RRLRx7Y6T7JkhfNuCPVW6yCGoyyh6Gs_YJRnhB9pwyhvSpKgjf54iN-tRJXzR_HK_GY40e3VtCl6IWPaprB92CAD1CkKISjjFQw_vHLW77CZu19HXWRgH2DhA0xooMiJBHOQwKm2RoRfslh3XewZzYLTG3sRbLMWZWlBn_HMDCJfi0Ek-KCPpPq-gxd4ZWrWdDm0DHTOclf47n2mY3WI0uATrPrBgWfI6EjzrGqmXh9nUbS-OS9XgYPydpFYnvKygF6d8jRQ9VXfM8UGSIspVH11ufL1Nhkm6YPFGwkeQ7UnCTlKXL1V9F6Q9IPbLI&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) are some more examples:

```
81 3^4 121 11^2
>
1476326929 7^2 * 11^2 * 499^2 1891467081 3^2 * 7^2 * 19^2 * 109^2
>
10994571025 5^2 * 67^2 * 313^2 13884144561 3^2 * 7^2 * 31^2 * 181^2
>
61436066769 3^2 * 7^2 * 11^2 * 29^2 * 37^2 120776405841 3^2 * 7^2 * 13^2 * 19^2 * 67^2
>
98551417041 3^6 * 7^2 * 11^2 * 151^2 190189315449 3^2 * 7^2 * 19^2 * 1093^2
>
119582481249 3^4 * 7^2 * 11^2 * 499^2 228867516801 3^2 * 7^2 * 11^2 * 19^2 * 109^2
>
141447449025 3^2 * 5^2 * 25073^2 253358202409 13^2 * 31^2 * 1249^2
>
220545762129 3^2 * 7^2 * 11^2 * 19^2 * 107^2 433950245001 3^2 * 7^2 * 13^2 * 19^2 * 127^2
>
388895668225 5^2 * 191^2 * 653^2 485512123369 7^2 * 13^4 * 19^2 * 31^2
>
619568914129 11^2 * 163^2 * 439^2 686781810729 3^2 * 7^2 * 19^2 * 31^2 * 67^2
>
890560253025 3^4 * 5^2 * 67^2 * 313^2 1679981491881 3^2 * 7^2 * 11^2 * 31^2 * 181^2
>
970952066161 7^2 * 11^2 * 67^2 * 191^2 1266928085241 3^2 * 7^4 * 13^2 * 19^2 * 31^2
>
2580138650961 3^2 * 29^2 * 37^2 * 499^2 3974915450961 3^2 * 7^2 * 13^2 * 67^2 * 109^2
>
3076652813521 7^2 * 83^2 * 3019^2 3623803369641 3^2 * 7^2 * 13^2 * 19^2 * 367^2
>
3739640454225 3^2 * 5^2 * 13^2 * 47^2 * 211^2 7445874636369 3^2 * 13^2 * 31^2 * 37^2 * 61^2
>
4138876942929 3^6 * 151^2 * 499^2 6259388523129 3^2 * 7^2 * 109^2 * 1093^2
>
4758545225281 19^2 * 29^2 * 37^2 * 107^2 5396129223849 3^2 * 7^2 * 13^2 * 67^2 * 127^2
>
9262289646801 3^2 * 19^2 * 107^2 * 499^2 14281891581321 3^2 * 7^2 * 13^2 * 109^2 * 127^2
```

Comment: Is it true that $\sigma(m^2)$ is not a perfect square for any odd $m$? You already give the example $m=1$. There's also $\sigma(9^2)=11^2$. It suffices to show that there is no odd integer $m$ such that $\sigma^k(m^2)$ is a perfect square *for all $k\geq0$*.

Comment: @Servaes: Yes, this step is missing.

Comment: It is nearly trivial to show that every number that is *not* an odd perfect square is eventually mapped to $1$. Why not ask about the nontrivial part of the question only? You could leave some of the context, but the question really boils down to what I wrote in my previous comment.

Comment: The sequence $\sigma^k(n)$ is similar to the [aliquot sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliquot_sequence) of $n$. Perhaps the sources there have some relevant information?

Comment: @Servaes: Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Nice to see so many more examples! And interesting to see so many recurring factors... Are these *all* such numbers up to some upper bound? Or did you find these by only considering specific factorizations?

Comment: And I wonder whether there exist examples of length $3$, i.e. natural numbers $n$ such that $n$, $\sigma(n)$ and $\sigma^2(n)$ are odd perfect squares...

Comment: @Servaes: I searched up to an upper bound. See the sage script.

Comment: I'd venture a guess that for any $K\geq0$ there exists $n\geq0$ such that $\sigma^k(n)$ is an odd perfect square for all $k\leq K$, but never for *all* $k\geq0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Partial answer:** Your function $C:\ \Bbb{N}\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{N}$ can also be described as follows:
$$C(n)=\begin{cases}\varphi(n)&\text{ if $n$ is even}\\\sigma(n)&\text{ if $n$ is odd}\end{cases}.$$
Of course $\varphi(n)$ is even for every $n\geq3$, so for even $n$ we get $\varphi^{k}(n)\leq2$ for sufficiently large $k$. As $\varphi(2)=\varphi(1)=1$ this shows that every even number ends up at $1$.

Similarly $\sigma(n)$ is even for every odd $n$ that is not a perfect square, and so every odd number $n$ that is not a perfect square also ends up at $1$. So the question that remains is:

> Is there an odd perfect square $n$ such that $\sigma^k(n)$ is an odd perfect square for *all* $k\in\Bbb{N}$?

This seems **extremely** unlikely, but I do not have a proof. The examples
$$\sigma(1^2)=1^2\qquad\text{ and }\qquad \sigma(9^2)=11^2,$$
show that it *is* possible for the divisor sum of an odd perfect square to be an odd perfect square again. Perhaps one can show that the number of prime factors is decreasing in any such sequence $(\sigma^k(n))_{k\in\Bbb{N}}$? Or perhaps there is a useful result on the related [aliquot sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliquot_sequence), which have been studied in more detail?

Comment: Thank you, I edited the question by your suggestion.

Comment: I found more examples like your $9,11$ example and updated the question.